# Clickear Imagen dentro de un Fragment y mostrarla expandida en otro, se puede?

Tags: android, imagen, android-fragment, android-imageview

**Esta es una CircleImageView, la cual utilizo como foto de perfil del usuario y esta dentro de un Fragment, el cual muestro en un viewPager, yo quiero saber si puedo tocarla asi peuqeña como esta y mostrarla completamente expandida dentro algun contenedor o hasta crear un nuevo Fragment y mostrarla, alguien podria ayudarme porfa.**
[image]
**Este es el codigo del metodo dentro del MainActivity, el cual llamo desde mi FragmentProfile tocando la imageView que deseo ampliar**

```
public void showImageFullScreen(ImageView imgageView){
    if (fragmentManager != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_left_to_right, R.anim.exit_right_to_left, R.anim.enter_right_to_left, R.anim.exit_right_to_left);
        ft.replace(R.id.container_fragment_profile, new AccountFragment(),"AccountFragment");
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**Este es el codigo dentro de mi ProfileFragment, Se que es una mala practica tratar de cargar una imagen dentro de otro fragment, pero si tienen alguna idea por favor les agradeceria su ayuda, no se...**

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.img_photo_profile_toolbar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Expandir foto perfil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((ProfileActivity)Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).showImageFullScreen(photoProfileToolbar);
            //photoProfileToolbar.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            //photoProfileToolbar.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Que tal compañero, justamente he estado trabajando algo parecido en mi proyecto, te cuento que en mi caso, al tocar el `CircleImageView` mando al usuario a una actividad y no a un fragmente, ahí realizo un `CircleImageView` más grande y le agrego una animación de elementos compartido para que tenga el efecto que al abrir la imagen, esta se traslada al actividad y viceversa. Si quieres te puedo pasar mi código e imágenes para que te sirva de guía.

Comment: **Se lo agradeceria paracero, porque hasta ahora lo unico que hice fue mostrar por medio de un AlertDialog la imagen que toque**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estoy realizando es que al tocar el `CircleImageView` abra una `Activity` dedicada a mostrar la imagen actual pero más grande y permitirle al usuario cambiarla si así lo desea:

```
imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Envia al usuario a la actividad perfil
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_MenuLateral.this, Activity_Perfil.class);
//El ActivityOptions es para realizar la animación entre objetos compartidos
//Debes pasarle la vista (v) y luego en el StartActivity pasas el options.Bundle
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity_MenuLateral.this, v, v.getTransitionName());
            ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(Activity_MenuLateral.this,i,request_code,options.toBundle());
//Aquí utilizo un ActivityForResult ya que necesito obtener una respuesta,
//pero puedes hacerlo con un StartActivity normal
        }
    });
```

Luego debes agregar la etiqueta `android:transitionName="MiAnimacion"` con el mismo nombre a ambos **XML**, uno en donde tienes la imagen pequeña y la otra en donde tienes la imagen grande.

Ya solo queda agregar la imagen mediante `Glide` si es que la estas guardando en un servidor o en `Firebase`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te halla dado una idea, si tienes dudas con las animaciones entre elementos compartidos puedes consultar la documentación oficial en donde encontraras ejemplos: [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity.html?hl=es-419#start-with-element)

Comment: ** Amigo muchas gracias ome, esta super el diseño de su App, yo soy nuevo en esto y en serio valoro la ayuda que presta toda la comunidad ome, gracias parcero**

Comment: como haces esto pero usando un fragment para detalles???